# Two Ubuntu servers in same IP address

Tags: networking, server, ip

**My case:**
I have Ubuntu server(20.04.3) installed in machine 1. This machine use 192.xxx.xx.500.

**What I need:**
I have another Ubuntu server in another machine and want to have same ip adress on machine 1.

---

Is it possible? Is there something I can type on netplan config file to make it work?

I need this because I have multiple ports on this ip and want to continue to use it.

Comment: Maybe elaborate on what "I have multiple ports on this ip" means, because I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: No. Not possible. "I need this because I have multiple ports on this ip and want to continue to use it." this sentence makes no sense to me ;)

Comment: It is actually possible, but it will not work. But I guess that's what you mean. 

Comment: Note also that 500 is not a valid octet.  Machine addresses must be in the range of 1-254 typically and only 0-255 are valid addresses.    I assume you faked that number as an example.   Overall, this sounds like an X-Y problem.  You can't do this, tell us why you want to do this so we can suggest correct solutions rather than invalid one you have focused on.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a viable solution. Giving 2 machines on the same network the same IP address will result in an IP conflict, where the networking on none of the machines will work properly.

You should think about what you want to do, and how to do this with the servers having different IP addresses.

The typical scenario when you have multiple services on different ports (and on different machines) is to do port forwarding in your firewall, so requests going to Port XXX is forwarded to internal IP 1.2.3.4, whereas Port YYY is forwarded to internal IP 1.2.3.5 etc.

However, configuring your firewall (unless your firewall is running Ubuntu) is not inside the scope for this site (but might be suitable for [Superuser](https://superuser.com/)).

Answer (score 2):

Having the same IP address on multiple machines is not going to work.

Having who machines with separate IP addresses, where one machine listens on both ports X and Y, but forwards requests on port Y to another IP address, so it *appears* as if that one machine runs services on ports X and Y *is* possible.

Depending on the protocol that "forwarding" may be easy or hard. For HTTP this is called a reverse proxy. For e.g. SNMP this is very tricky (impossible?) to get working well.

Comment: I don't think you actually need a reverse proxy for this type of forwarding. For any TCP-based protocol using a single connection (ie. not for example for FTP) just simple port forwarding (like socat, tcppm or similar) from port Y on machine 1 to port Z on machine 2 should work. It's the same how port forwarding in home routers works.

Answer (score 0):

contrary to the other two answers it is possible to have the same IP address on two separate machines using [anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast).  For this to work you would generally configure the shared (anycast) address on either the loopback or dummy interface, as a second address.  You would then need to announce the address to your router via some routing protocol e.g. ospf, bgp.  static routes on the router would also work

This type of configuration can allow one to preform load balancing at the router however make sure to enable [ECMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-cost_multi-path_routing) if you are trying to load balance TCP